# 'Extra-high-voltage grid' or 'extra-high voltage grid'?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I've seen both used interchangeably, and can't decide which is best. Given that both adjectives modify the noun, should two hyphens not be used? Thanks!

Comment: Extra-high-voltage grid = [extra-high voltage] [grid] whereas extra-high voltage grid = [extra-high] [voltage grid]. The second is incorrect; it's a grid working at extra-high voltage, and both hyphens are needed to convey this (there _are_ admittedly situations where the meaning is so clear that 'necessary' hyphens are dropped).

Comment: An 'extra-high voltage grid' sounds like a 'voltage grid', whatever that is, at a particularly high altitude. The whole compound adjective needs to be hyphenated.